# sending multiple props to component in Router (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to send props but it's not working in the way I expected.

In this case, only `newDataCount` is sent properly and the `props={props}`is undefined.

```js
const {newDataCount} = useContext(JobInfoContext);

return( <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${path}`}
          render={(props) => (
            <Check newDataCount={newDataCount} props={props} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>);
```

and in this case, only `{...props}` is sent properly and `newDataCount`is undefined.

```js
const {newDataCount} = useContext(JobInfoContext);

return( <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${path}`}
          render={(props) => (
            <Check {...props} newDataCount={newDataCount} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>);
```

How can I send both props?

Comment: `props={props}` doesn't make sense.  There is no prop called `props` so it should always be `{...props}`.  That said, I'm not sure why the second one isn't working.

Comment: are you sure that you React.createContext() somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please try this one. It will work for you:-

```
const {newDataCount} = useContext(JobInfoContext);

return( <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${path}`}
          component={(props) => (
            <Check {...props} newDataCount={newDataCount} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>);
```